# How to lookup or aggregate a field of an object in an array of javascript objects (in mongodb)?

Tags: mongodb, lookup, aggregation, mongoose-schema, unwind-segue

I want have the field **contractType** in my mongoose schema, is an array of objects that each one has the property **authorizedBy** into the second level.

**contractType** field could have many items and I want to know each **authorizedBy** finding it in other collection called **admins** (I'll let it below too).

```
const professionalSchema = new Schema(
  firstName: String,
  contractType: [
    new Schema(
      {
        contract: String,
        authorizedBy: {
          type: ObjectId,
          ref: 'admin',
          index: true,
        },
        document: String
      },
      {
        timestamps: true,
        versionKey: false,
      },
    ),
  ],
)
```

this is my admin collection.

```
const adminSchema = new Schema(
  {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    role: String
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
  },
)
```

I have this in **professionalSchema** mongodb compass:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6009a0d0874f0900086ee0ce"),
  "firstName": "xxxx",
  "gender": "NOT_SPECIFIED",
  "contractType": [
    {
      "authorizedBy": ObjectId("5fad90665d963cbbbd4a6580"),
      "document": "document 1"
    },
    {
      "authorizedBy": ObjectId("5fad90665d963cbbbd4a6580"),
      "document": "document 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

this is an admin of the collection of admins (**adminSchema**):

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5fad90665d963cbbbd4a6580"),
  "role": "SAM",
  "firstName": "firstname",
  "lastName": "lastname"
}
```

**I would have response like this one below, additionally I want to get all fields of the object (20 aprox) not adding each one manually, like spread operator (...item) in javascript**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6009a0d0874f0900086ee0ce"),
  "firstName": "xxxx",
  "contractType": [
    {
      "authorizedBy": {
        "_id": "5fad90665d963cbbbd4a6580",
        "firstName": "firstname",
        "lastName": "lastname",
        "role": "SAM"
      },
      "document": "document 1"
    },
    {
      "authorizedBy": {
        "_id": "5fad90665d963cbbbd4a6580",
        "firstName": "firstname",
        "lastName": "lastname",
        "role": "SAM"
      },
      "document": "document 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried this in mongo compass.

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      '_id': new ObjectId('6009a0d0874f0900086ee0ce')
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$contractType'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'admins', 
      'localField': 'contractType.authorizedBy', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'contractType.authorizedBy'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$contractType.authorizedBy'
  }
  }, {
    $group': {
      '_id': '$_id'
    }
  }
]
```

**but I don't know how put rest of elements (20 aprox) in the same object :(**

Comment: Can you share example input and expected output?

Comment: I update the question with that info :D

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is almost correct,

```
db.professionalSchema.aggregate([
  {"$match": {"_id": ObjectId("6009a0d0874f0900086ee0ce") } },
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$contractType" }},
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "adminSchema",
      "localField": "contractType.authorizedBy",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "contractType.authorizedBy"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "contractType.authorizedBy": {
        $ifNull: [
          {  $arrayElemAt: [ "$contractType.authorizedBy", 0 ] },
          ""
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "firstName": { $first: "$firstName" },
      "gender": { $first: "$gender"},
      contractType: { $push: "$contractType" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v8pifXC-rPW)**

Comment: but if in my professionalSchema I have more than 20 fields and some of these have embedded document...  Is there a way to pass all properties to the the result of group? like spread operator in javascript {...items}